# How can I get username and password from SharedPreferences in Android?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to recover the username and password to be able to start a session.
These are the users of the sharedPreferences.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="admin">1234</string>
    <string name="user">user0987</string>
</map>
```

And this is the method

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        SharedPreferences sp1 = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String user = sp1.getString(userInput.getText().toString(), "User not found");
        String pass = sp1.getString(passwordInput.getText().toString(), "Password is not correct");
        
        if(user.equals(userInput.getText().toString()){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
});
```

This is the code that puts data in SharedPreferences

```
register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       
        String user = userInput.getText().toString();
        String pass = passwordInput.getText().toString();

        if(user.isEmpty()){
            error.show();
        } else if (pass.isEmpty()){
            error2.show();
        } else{
            SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor Ed=sp.edit();
            Ed.putString(user,pass);
            Ed.commit();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Register completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Please add code for storing data to `SharedPreferences`

Comment: I have already added it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use next code when you retrieve data from SP:

```
SharedPreferences sp1 = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String pass = sp1.getString(userInput.getText().toString(), null);
if (pass != null) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

You are saving data in form of "user:pasword", so you need to get it the same way, using user name as the key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add keys for saving for data in `SharedPreferences` editor.

Currently you are using entered username as key, It can be change according to entered data in edittext, because user will not enter same username every time, but for saving and getting data to/from `SharedPreferences` we need a specific key.

You can add keys for saving user name and password like following code:

```
 SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor ed=sp.edit();
 ed.putString("user",user);
 ed.putString("pass",pass);
 ed.commit();
```

For getting data

```
SharedPreferences sp1 = getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String userName = sp1.getString("user", "User not found");
String password = sp1.getString("pass", "Password is not correct");
```

For more info regarding  Sharedpref check [Official documentation for Save key-value data using SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

Comment: This is what I have tried at the beginning, but the problem is that if I want to add more than one user, it overwrites the one already created.